# HapiJS and Sequelize without Sequelize CLI

Tags: sequelize.js, hapi.js

I'm trying to start a project using [HapiJS](http://hapijs.com/) and [Sequelize](http://sequelizejs.com) and for a started, want to get things working without the `Sequelize CLI` to understand how everything goes together. 
I've seen multiple example projects such as :

> https://github.com/jean-rakotozafy/sequelize-hapi-example
>
> https://github.com/miguelcobain/hapi-boilerplate

And they all seem to use Sequelize CLI, which I would like to avoid for a starter.
Is there any open source project I can get an inspiration from ?

**Otherwise** : How can I avoid using the automatically generated [index.js](https://github.com/jean-rakotozafy/sequelize-hapi-example/blob/master/models/index.js) in those files, at least to read them in a certain order ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sequelize is very simple to configure. You don't need any sequelize cli. Just do: `npm install sequelize` and configure it. Here is my config file:

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const config = require("./config.js"));
require('sequelize-isunique-validator')(Sequelize);

const db = new Sequelize(config.db_name, config.db_username, 
config.db_password, {
    host: "localhost",
    dialect: "mysql",
});


module.exports = db;
```

And in config file:

```
const config = {
    db_username: "your database login",
    db_password: "your database password",
    db_name: "your database name"
};

module.exports = config;
```

With that being set, you can now create simple model:

```
const db = require("./db.js"));
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");

const user = db.define("user", {
    id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
    username: { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false }
});

module.exports = user;
```

And then use it like in [Sequelize documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-usage.html)